# Why am I Getting an Error on Gcloud Deploy?

Tags: python-3.x, gcloud

I am trying to launch a test website using glcloud and when I run

`gcloud app deploy`

I get the following error in the logs

```
Running "python3 -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt --upgrade --upgrade-strategy only-if-needed --no-warn-script-location --no-warn-conflicts --force-reinstall --no-compile --user (PIP_CACHE_DIR=/layers/google.python.pip/pipcache PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1)"
Processing /opt/conda/conda-bld/flask_1648041541647/work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/conda/conda-bld/flask_1648041541647/work'

Done "python3 -m pip install --requirement requirements.txt --upgr..." (781.993462ms)
Failure: (ID: c84b3231) Processing /opt/conda/conda-bld/flask_1648041541647/work
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/conda/conda-bld/flask_1648041541647/work'
```

Does anyone know why this could be happening? I'm on a windows machine but I'm assuming this code isn't running locally. I have a requirements file and it looks like it's respecting the runtime environment (python 3.9) I'm requesting so I'm unsure what to try.

requirements.txt

```
argcomplete==1.12.3
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==20.3.0
certifi==2021.10.8
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.4
Flask @ file:///opt/conda/conda-bld/flask_1648041541647/work
iniconfig==1.1.1
itsdangerous @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/itsdangerous_1621432558163/work
Jinja2 @ file:///opt/conda/conda-bld/jinja2_1647436528585/work
MarkupSafe @ file:///C:/ci/markupsafe_1621528502553/work
packaging==20.9
pipx==0.16.1.0
pluggy==0.13.1
py==1.10.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.2.3
toml==0.10.2
userpath==1.4.2
Werkzeug @ file:///opt/conda/conda-bld/werkzeug_1645628268370/work
wincertstore==0.2
```

app.yaml (edited to work with flex)

```
runtime: python
env: flex
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Comment: Please include the `requirements.txt` and `app.yaml` in your question to help us help you. I suspect (!?) you're using App Engine standard (not flex) and that `conda` (I'm unfamiliar with it) is non-pure Python which requires compilation which is a constraint of the runtime.

Comment: I added the requirements and app files. You are correct that I'm using App Engine and I went there and switched the type to flexible and then re-ran gcloud init and told it to override the existing settings. The build log remains the same though so that may not be the way to change it.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. You'll need to add `env:flex` and tweak `runtime: python` to deploy as flex see [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml)

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Flex environment only supports the following python_versions: 2, 3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 according to this [file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml).